# Set-DefaultScaffolder error on starting NuGet Package Manager console in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

I am getting the following errors when PMC is started in VS 2013:

[image: Default Scaffolder]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

[That's because `DTE` in VS2013 has another name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68shb4dw.aspx), and the call to `DTE` crashes.

[David Douglas Anderson provided a new package that resolves this problem](https://github.com/processedbeets/ASP.NET-MVC-Scaffolding). [We are working on an issue to make this package work with VS2013](https://github.com/processedbeets/ASP.NET-MVC-Scaffolding/issues/1). As soon David get to update and publish the [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcScaffolding.VS2015/), I'll be updating this answer.

---

**EDIT**

David finally got the packages to work, so [MvcScaffolding.VS2015](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcScaffolding.VS2015/) has support for VS2013 and 2015.